# How to indicate profile in actuator/bus-refresh request whit spring cloud bus

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, profile, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-bus

My environment:

- spring-cloud:Finchley.SR2
- spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp or spring-cloud.starter-bus-roketmq
- spring-cloud-config-server / client

there is two project - config-server and client named Gateway(spring.application.name). i test it in devel profile, client(Gateway) will refresh correct when i:

- request /actuator/bus-refresh
- request /actuator/bus-refresh/**
- request /actuator/bus-refresh/Gateway
- request /actuator/bus-refresh/Gateway:**

now i wanna explicit indicate the profile in Gateway, like "/actuator/bus-refresh/Gateway:devel" or some other format, what should i do?

Comment: or the /actuator/bus-refresh only can refresh client with same profile as config-server??